# How to make the animation smooth and keep constraints from the RecyclerView?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, animation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZL64.gif)

```
class ClubCardsPricesFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_club_cards_prices, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val items = listOf(
            ClubCardPrices(R.drawable.some_people, "Друзья", "", "1 год", "с 7:00 до 23:00", "Тренажерный зал, залы групповых программ, бассейн, турецкая и русская бани, фитнес тестирование", "60 дней", "3 водных инструктажа", "3 гостевых визизта"),
            ClubCardPrices(R.drawable.some_people, "Индивидуальная", "", "1 год", "с 7:00 до 23:00", "Тренажерный зал, залы групповых программ, бассейн, турецкая и русская бани, фитнес тестирование", "60 дней", "3 водных инструктажа", "3 гостевых визизта"),
            ClubCardPrices(R.drawable.some_people, "Индивидуальная", "", "1 год", "с 7:00 до 23:00", "Тренажерный зал, залы групповых программ, бассейн, турецкая и русская бани, фитнес тестирование", "60 дней", "3 водных инструктажа", "3 гостевых визизта"),
            ClubCardPrices(R.drawable.some_people, "Индивидуальная", "", "1 год", "с 7:00 до 23:00", "Тренажерный зал, залы групповых программ, бассейн, турецкая и русская бани, фитнес тестирование", "60 дней", "3 водных инструктажа", "3 гостевых визизта"),
            ClubCardPrices(R.drawable.some_people, "Индивидуальная", "", "1 год", "с 7:00 до 23:00", "Тренажерный зал, залы групповых программ, бассейн, турецкая и русская бани, фитнес тестирование", "60 дней", "3 водных инструктажа", "3 гостевых визизта")
        )
        val clubCardsPricesRecyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.card_types_recyclerview1)
        clubCardsPricesRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        clubCardsPricesRecyclerView.adapter = ClubCardPricesAdapter(items) { item, cardImage, cardName ->
         /*

code for realization listener
*/ }
        val cardsCategories = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.cards_categories_textview)
        val initialHeight = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 170.toFloat(), resources.displayMetrics).toInt()
        var isExpanded = false
        cardsCategories.setOnClickListener{
            val targetHeight = if (isExpanded) initialHeight else 80
            isExpanded = !isExpanded

            val anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(cardsCategories.height, targetHeight)
            anim.addUpdateListener { valueAnimator ->
                val value = valueAnimator.animatedValue as Int
                cardsCategories.layoutParams.height = value
                cardsCategories.requestLayout()
            }
            anim.duration = 2000
            anim.start()

            for (i in 0 until items.size) {
                val viewHolder = clubCardsPricesRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i) as ClubCardPricesAdapter.ViewHolder
                val lp = viewHolder.itemView.layoutParams as RecyclerView.LayoutParams
                val targetMargin = if(isExpanded) 0 else -i*TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 160.toFloat(), resources.displayMetrics).toInt()
                val anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(lp.topMargin, targetMargin)
                anim.addUpdateListener { valueAnimator ->
                    val animatedValue = valueAnimator.animatedValue as Int
                    lp.topMargin = animatedValue
                    viewHolder.itemView.layoutParams = lp
                }
                anim.duration = 1000
                anim.start()
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = ClubCardsPricesFragment()
    }
}

class ClubCardPricesAdapter(private val items: List<ClubCardPrices>, private val listener: (ClubCardPrices, ImageView, TextView) -> Unit) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ClubCardPricesAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.card_type_element, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val offsetY = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 160.toFloat(), holder.itemView.context.resources.displayMetrics).toInt()
        val item = items[position]
        holder.bind(item, listener)
        val layoutParams = holder.itemView.layoutParams as RecyclerView.LayoutParams
        layoutParams.topMargin = offsetY*-position
        holder.itemView.layoutParams = layoutParams

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items.size
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        fun bind(item: ClubCardPrices, listener: (ClubCardPrices, ImageView, TextView) -> Unit) = with(itemView) {
            val cardImage = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.card_type_image)
            val cardName = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.card_type_name)
            val cardPersonsAmount = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.card_type_personamount)
            val cardTerm = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.card_type_term)
            val cardLayout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.card_type_linearlayout)
            cardImage.setImageResource(item.image)
            cardName.text = item.title
            cardPersonsAmount.text = item.personosAmount
            cardTerm.text = item.term
            setOnClickListener { listener(item, cardImage, cardName) }
        }
    }
}

data class ClubCardPrices(val image: Int, val title: String, val personosAmount: String, val term: String, val time: String, val abilities: String, val freezing: String, val inductionTrainings: String, val guestVisits: String) : Serializable
```

I have a working fragment code, but during the animation they do not move smoothly, but twitch from side to side. And also the bottom TextView, which is attached to the bottom of the RecyclerView, does not move along with the bottom element and twitches during animation. How can this be corrected to achieve a smooth ride?